# How can I create a "shortcut" for the built in PDF viewer on Nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7, home-screen, home-screen-shortcuts, pdf

The Nexus 7 has a default PDF viewer, but it's a little hard to get to. How can I put an shortcut for it on my home screen?
Note that the default program (Document Viewer) doesn't show up in the list of apps. I can see it in the running apps (when it is) and in Settings > Apps > All ... it doesn't show up in the app drawer (the 6 dots in a circle).

Comment: If it shows under all apps then [QuickShortcutMaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut&hl=en) would help you to make the shortcut out of it.